# Objective C Send Color to Method

Tags: objective-c, methods, uicolor

Is there a way of sending a UIColor to a method so I can set a group of stuff with one call

Something like this:

```
[self setall:[UIColor yellowColor]];


-(void) setall:(UIColor *) colmethod {
    tcol.textColor=[colmethod];
    [eee setTitleColor:[colmethod] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [savecol setTitleColor:[colmethod] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [picklogo setTitleColor:[colmethod] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    labcol.textColor=[colmethod];
    [bckcol setTitleColor:[colmethod] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [svecol setTitleColor:[colmethod] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    border1.layer.borderColor = [colmethod].CGColor;
    logo.layer.borderColor = [colmethod].CGColor;
    border2.layer.borderColor = [colmethod].CGColor;
}
```

I am trying to set all options with one call as I have to do it 10 times depending on a switch

Any help appreciated

Mark

Comment: Is your question about the vast number of syntax errors in the code you posted?

Comment: did you mean. `[self setall:[UIColor yellowColor]];`

Comment: sorry just trying to have a guess on how its done edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method should be something like this,

```
-(void)setColor : (UIColor *)myColor{

   myView.backgroundColor = myColor;
   someView.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor
   //etc
  }
```

Call this method like,

```
[sel setColor : [UIColor redColor]]; //or whatever color you want to set
```

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for you kind help it works fine on text colours but won't work on button borders. I have tried [eee setTitleColor:[myColor.CGColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; AND
    [savecol setTitleColor:[myColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; but i get a expected identifier error

Comment: if you want to set border color then you should set to it's layer and you have to type cast uicolor to cgcolor

Comment: Sorry still learning I don't quite understand this. I normally put the following: [eee setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; which changes the buttons border to blue I want to replace the UIColor blueColor with what comes in to the method so by specifying different colours it changes them all to same

Comment: why am i being downvoted so much for a simple error

Comment: You're not replacing `UIColor blueColor`, you're replacing [UIColor blueColor]`. In Obj-c, backets [a b] mean "send method b to object a". When you call `[sel setColor : [UIColor redColor]]` setColor now has the resulting color object in `myColor`, so you don't need the brackets: just `[savecol setTitleColor:myColor forState:UIControlStateNormal]

Comment: mackworth your a star thank you so much I understand now you have restored my faith that people on here really do help newbies like me

Comment: If you are setting bordercolor then you should give border width also to make it visible. like, someView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

Comment: thank you lion better get off this one now before i get down voted any more